# C# - Async method return data from ContinueWith

Tags: c#, asynchronous, windows-phone-8, async-await

I have a Windows Phone app that gets data from an RSS Feed and caches the previous articles.

```
public class MainViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    private ObservableCollection<Article> _articles;
}
```

In my viewmodel, I'd like to be able to load the cached data via an async method and ContinueWith loading the online data via another async method, so that the app can quickly display data as it loads the web content. My code currently looks something like this:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => _model.LoadDataAsync())
    .ContinueWith(antecendent => _model.RefreshDataAsync())
    .Wait();
```

where the **LoadDataAsync** and **RefreshDataAsync** methods return **List<Article>**.

```
public async Task<List<Article>> LoadDataAsync() { ... }
public async Task<List<Article>> RefreshDataAsync() { ... }
```

However, when I try to assign that result to my articles:

```
_articles = await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => _modelArticles.LoadDataAsync())
    .ContinueWith(antecendent => _modelArticles.RefreshDataAsync())
    .Wait();
```

It tells me that I *"cannot await a void"*. So what can I do to my code to allow it to give me the **LoadDataAsync** List first, and add the **RefreshDataAsync** List once it completes?

For those who are familiar with it, I'm looking to emulate the behavior of the [WPCentral](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-ph/store/app/wpcentral/e6c3c78a-4382-e011-986b-78e7d1fa76f8) app, that shows cached articles, and then fades out and in with new articles.

Comment: What are the method signatures for `LoadDataAsync()` and `RefreshDataAsync()`?

Comment: @KirillShlenskiy Will edit

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error message is because your code is `await`ing the result of `Wait`, which is `void` (and not `await`able). You should remove the call to `Wait`.

More tips:

- Use [`Task.Run` instead of `Task.Factory.StartNew`](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html) (as I describe on my blog).
- [Don't use `Wait` with asynchronous tasks](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) (again, link to my blog).
- Use `await` instead of `ContinueWith`.
- Consider using [`NotifyTaskCompletion`](https://nitoasyncex.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=NotifyTaskCompletion) from my [AsyncEx library](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Nito.AsyncEx/) if you want to make asynchronous operations data-bindable.

You could try this first:

```
_articles = await Task.Run(() => _modelArticles.LoadDataAsync());
_articles = await Task.Run(() => _modelArticles.RefreshDataAsync());
```

But I'm not convinced `Task.Run` is necessary:

```
_articles = await _modelArticles.LoadDataAsync();
_articles = await _modelArticles.RefreshDataAsync();
```

Comment: Edit: removed comment as you have addressed all my points. +1.

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer. If I use your method (the one without Task.Run), is there any way I can include ContinueWith to have it all on one line? Sorry if I'm being nitpicky, but I'm just wondering if that's possible :)

Comment: +1 for the amazing explanations you provide on your blog

Comment: @miguelarcilla: Technically, you could, but `ContinueWith` is intended for use when your code is doing [dynamic Task-based parallelism](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff963551.aspx). It's not intended for use with `async` code because it [has some dangerous default behavior](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/10/continuewith-is-dangerous-too.html) (link to my blog). IMO the `await` code is clearer and safer.

Comment: @StephenCleary Got it. I was just being a little anal about it since the viewmodel is for a Panorama and gets data from multiple models, was hoping I could do a "one-model one-line" kinda thing. Thanks a lot and great blog! I'll definitely be using it as a reference in the future :)